# Arithmetic + and Bitwise OR

Tags: c#, java

Is there any difference between Arithmetic + and bitwise OR. In what way this is differing.

```
uint a = 10;
uint b = 20;

uint  arithmeticresult = a + b;

uint bitwiseOR = a | b;
```

Both the results are 30.

Edit : Small changes to hide my stupidity.

Comment: oops i forgot my school day lessons (Fundamentals).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`(10 | 20) == 10 + 20` only because the 1-bits do not appear in the same digit.

```
       1010 = 10
   or 10100 = 20
   ————————
      11110 = 30
```

However,

```
    11 = 3        11 = 3
or 110 = 6     + 110 = 6
——————         ——¹——————
   111 = 7      1001 = 9
#   ^             ^
# (1|1==1)      (1+1=2)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Counterexample:**

`2 + 2 == 4`
`2 | 2 == 2`

Bitwise OR means, for each bit position in both numbers, if one or two bits are on, then the result bit is on.  Example:

```
0b01101001
|
0b01011001
=
0b01111001
```

(`0b` is a prefix for binary literals supported in some programming languages)

At the bit level, addition is similar to bitwise OR, except that it carries:

```
0b01101001
+
0b01011001
=
0b11000010
```

In your case, 10+20 and 10|20 happen to be the same because 10 (`0b1010`) and 20 (`0b10100`) have no 1s in common, meaning no carry happens in addition.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting a = 230 and b = 120. And you'll observer the difference in results.

The reason is very simple. In the arithmentic addition operation the bit-wise add operation may generate **carry bit** which is added in the next bit-wise addition on the bit-pair available on the subsequent position. But in case of bit wise OR it just performs ORing which never generates a carry bit.

> **The fact that you're getting same result in your case is that the
>   numbers co-incidentally don't generate any
>   carry-bit during addition.**

Bit-wise arithmetic Addition

[alt text http://www.is.wayne.edu/drbowen/casw01/AnimAdd.gif](http://www.is.wayne.edu/drbowen/casw01/AnimAdd.gif)

Comment: I think small is a poor way of expressing the problem.  You can come up with trivially large examples which have the same problem.  Let n be any "large enough" number to satisfy your "it's no longer small" criteria.  Then compare the bitwise-or and arithmetic add values of shifting 1 by n and (n-1).  See my point?  I think the important bit is that the binary representation of the numbers chosen were not sufficiently varied.  That said the animated gif was awesome. :)

Comment: completely agree with you. Updated my answer.

Comment: Where did you get that animation from?

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise OR goes through every bit of two digits and applies the following truth table:

```
A  B  | A|B
0  0  |  0
0  1  |  1
1  0  |  1
1  1  |  1
```

Meanwhile the arithmetic + operator actually goes through every bit applying the following table (where c is the carry-in, a and b are the bits of your number, s is the sum and c' is the carry out):

```
C  A  B  | S  C'
0  0  0  | 0  0
0  0  1  | 1  0
0  1  0  | 1  0
0  1  1  | 0  1
1  0  0  | 1  0
1  0  1  | 0  1
1  1  0  | 0  1
1  1  1  | 1  1
```

For obvious reasons, the carry-in starts-off being 0.

As you can see, sum is actually a lot more complicated.  As a side effect of this, though, there as an easy trick you can do to detect overflow when adding positive signed numbers.  More specifically, we expect that a+b >= a|b if that fails then you have an overflow!

The case when the two numbers will be the same is when every time a bit in one of the two numbers is set, the corresponding bit int he second number is NOT set.  That is to say that you have three possible states: either both bits aren't set, the bit is set in A but not B, or the bit is set in B but not A.  In that case the arithmetic + and the bit-wise or would produce the same result... as would the bitwise xor for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

Using arithmetic operations to manipulate bitmasks can produce unexpected results and even overflow. For instance, turning on the n-th bit of a bitmask if it is already on will turn off the n-th bit and turn on the n+1-th bit. This will cause overflow if there are only n-bits.

Example of turning on bit 2:

```
Arithmetic ADD      Bitwise OR
          0101            0101                                           
        + 0100          | 0100     
          ----            ----                                           
          1001            0101    //expected result: 0101
```

Like-wise, using arithmetic subtract to turn off the n-th bit will fail if the n-th bit was not already on.

Example of turning off bit 2:

```
Arithmetic SUB      Bitwise AND~
          0001              0001 
        - 0100           &~ 0100
          ----              ----
          0001              0001
        + 1100           &  1011
          ----              ----
          1101              0001   //expected result: 0001
```

So bitwise operators are safer than arithmetic operators when you are working with bitmasks.

The following bitwise operations have analogous arithmetic operations:

```
                    Bitwise            Arithmetic 
Check n-th bit      x  &  (1 << n)   !(x  - (1 << n))
Turn on n-th bit    x |=  (1 << n)     x += (1 << n)
Turn off n-th bit   x &= ~(1 << n)     x -= (1 << n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a = 1 and b = 1 ;)
+ and | have different when two bits at the same positions are 1

Answer (score 0):

```
  00000010

OR

  00000010

Result

  00000010

VS

  00000010

+

  00000010

Result

  00000100
```

Comment: To format "code", indent 4 spaces. The javascript editor on the site can also do it for you: highlight a few lines, then click on the 01010 button.