# Serial port read string

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a serial port app that read weighing machine.

```
    public void Read()
    {
        while (Puerto.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                string inputData = Puerto.ReadExisting();
                dataReceived = inputData;
            }
            catch (TimeoutException) { }
        }
    }
```

the return string is like this

[image: Data returned by weighing machine]

It has other extrange chars in it, how can i do to parse or get a clean data from it? all I need is **0.52lb**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what weighing machine is it and what the serial port specs on it but, if it is black box to you too then, check the following:
 - check if you have a technical spec that explains what comes out of RS232 port
 - do several (10?) samples with one sample weight and see if the number of bytes are delivered each time
    - if you see the number of bytes being constant (barring discrepancy in the 0.52lb text changing to 0.5lb once in a while), it is likely that garbage following the weight is additional binary data.
    - if not, and you see the weight (text) with exact offset each time, you just can scrape the output

this is complete reverse engineering, I suggest going after technical spec and doing more insightful data handling though.

Comment: You are right, other data is binary data, now my problem is how to proccess it. I'm not an expert on serial port comunications. In that data there is a status flags, how can i extract those Bytes and then each bite?

Comment: Extracting bytes is straight forward.  Read the stream out of the port as binary and parse the interesting part(s) of it. Key thing is for you to determine the structure of the data. If you are determined to reverse engineer, you must observe all possible cases of weight samples and observe the size and format.  As far as meaning of those bytes go, guessing is probably not the best way and there is no recommended approach for this.  Follow your instincts looking at the sample data - use both binary and text visualizers on it.

Comment: TKS for your interest on help me. Allready have the structure, now I'm dealling with the last 3 Bytes, they are flags of bite like this 10000001, how can i do to extract those bites from a byte ?

Comment: C# (looks like that's what you are using) supports bit arithmetic, see [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(v=vs.71).aspx), [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734981/arithmetic-and-bitwise-or), [link](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpLogicalBitwiseOps.aspx) for details.  As for 10000001, see below: 
<code>const byte WEIGHMENTFLAG1 = 0x80;
const byte WEIGHMENTFLAG2 = 0x01;

public static void Main(){
    byte _flags = 0x81;    // that's 10000001
    Console.WriteLine("FLAG1 is: " + ((_flags & WEIGHMENTFLAG1) != 0));
}</code>

Answer (score 1):

This could be anything - a bug in the weighing machine, some sort of hardware issue, or a problem in how the serial port is configured. I would suspect a configuration problem. Make sure all the settings are correct (BaudRate, Handshake, Parity, StopBits). Also, try connecting to the same serial port device using another program (e.g. see http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-hyperterminal/ ) and see if you see the same garbage data.